# Using XPath Contains and getting 'missing right parenthesis' error

Tags: java, sql, xml, xpath

I wish to use the xpath function 'contains' to extract data that contains 'Potter' but I keep getting a 'java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis' error, any help?

```
result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a.book.extract('/book/author/text()').getStringVal() "
                + "FROM BOOK a "
                + "WHERE a.book.existsNode('/book/title[contains(text(), 'Potter')]') = 1 ");
        System.out.println("\n------------Query 8 Results------------");
        System.out.println("Authors of Books whose title contains 'Potter': \n");
        while(result.next()){
            System.out.println(result.getString(1));
        }//end while
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
+ "WHERE a.book.existsNode('/book/title[contains(text(), 'Potter')]') = 1 ");
```

you have to escape the single quotes of 'Potter' in any way. Because your `existsNode` function already has single quotes for the value!

A **not tested** solution could be by replacing the inner single quotes with two single quotes like this:

```
+ "WHERE a.book.existsNode('/book/title[contains(text(), ''Potter'')]') = 1 ");
                                                         ^        ^
```

Comment: I used this solution and all was looking good until I got this error, java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long, any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quote problem.

I suggest you read this : 
http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00907_missing_right_parenthesis.htm

The inner quotes must be doubled in your case